# Is there a way to pass a mysql query securely from one page to another?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to pass a mysql query securely from one page to another?

Basicaly, i have a list of items that is generated by a mysql query and is limited to only 5 items.  I want to add a "more" link at the bottom that would take the user to a page that would display the same list but not have the 5 item limit.  Normally i would pass a set of parameters to the "more" page that i could use to re-create the query, but due to the fact that the list can be generated by a great number and diversity of queries, this is very hard.

So im wondering if there is a way to securely and easily pass a whole mysql query from one php page to another.  For instance, is there a way to make it so when you click a link, the query is stored in some databese with an ID assigned to it, and then one would simply have to pass the ID to the next page.

Comment: Why don't pass the data to assemble new query?

Comment: And make sure you sanitize the data.

Comment: Why not use a function and call it from the new page?

Comment: *Don't do this*. Please.

Comment: @ zerkms as i said, due to the fact that the list can be generated by a great number and diversity of queries, this is very hard

Comment: @user1373823: it's not a justification for choosing terribly wrong way

Answer (score 3):

**The "secure way to pass a query from one page to another" is to not pass it at all. Treating queries as data and passing them between pages is a very good way to accidentally create security vulnerabilities.**

Your logic for generating the query already exists, so just make that logic available to both pages. This generally is done via `require()`ing a file with shared code into the files for both pages.

Alternatively, just add an option to the page that's already generating the query to show the full set of items instead of just a subset - no need to have an entirely separate page.

Comment: the problem with not having a separate page for the entire list is that the full list can be hundreds of items long, which means it would require a pageing system.  And since there can be up to 5 lists on one page, pageing becomes complicated to do.

Comment: Then just share the logic, but there's no reason to be passing queries around. You might also consider looking into AJAX paging systems, or use something that's already been constructed for you like http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions to pass data across without it "escaping" the back-end realm.

Since the queries can come from many places, you may need to index the data by some arbitrary identifier key and pass that along in the URL.

**Update**

If the site is public (i.e. no login required), sessions prevent sharing a page easily with someone else.

In that case, you should have a way to identify all your queries, either using a database or from the code base itself (perhaps using a naming convention); the parameters are then sent via query parameters.

Comment: the problem with using sessions to pass the query is that you couldnt easily send a friend a link to the full list.  Is there any way to use sessions and bypass this problem?

Comment: @user1373823 in that case you should go for the second option; a query identifier that's passed and looked up via code / db

Comment: if i indexed each query, wouldnt that slow down the website?  For instance, each time you load a list, you would have to check if the list already exists in the index, and if it doesnt exist, add it.  And if there are 5 lists on, that quite a few extra queries.  Also, to pass the query on to another site, you would need to extract the indexed queries id from a database, which could mean another 5 queries.

Comment: @user1373823 What's a list and why would there be 5? The idea is that you can identify the query by some id, either via database or based on a naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use sessions, then encrypt the query with a private key, base64 encode it, and put it in a hidden input field on the page.

Comment: And in case of losing private key - you also lose database. Sneaky